# Laravel 5 CORS middleware not working for group of routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cross-domain, cors, middleware

I am appling cors middleware to access json from some other domain.

This code works just fine :-

```
Route::get('api/authenticate', ['middleware' => 'cors', function() {
    return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve Jobs', 'state' => 'California'));
}]);
```

But when I apply it to :-

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
```

it gives me error in console,

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I have a have added Cors middleware, cors.php :-

```
class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You might consider using [this package barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: I used this in couple of simple project and it worked fine. I am following this tutorial for token based authentication, and when applied to group of routes,it fails.https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: Did you find a solution on this @StacyJ ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find solution for mine as well when sending JWT into header. This is what resolved my case:

1) Add the cors in route middleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

2) Add the cors in global middlewre

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

3) Add custom Access-Control-Allow-Headers in Cors middleware app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Log;

class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        Log::info("Using cors for " . $request->url());
        return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');// <-- Adding this
    }
}
```